# How to SUM up the values of variable of all agents in a state in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have this model as shown in the image below,
[image]

I have a variable named variable. I want the sum up the value BUDGET of all agents that are in assessBids for the time being.

Lets suppose I have three agents waiting in assessbids state at time t1 for the next 1 day.

The value of budget for agent1 is 50, agent 2 is 55, agent 3 is 60.

I want to update the variable to 50+55+60 = 165.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop across the population of bidders from within your Bidder. First, understand OOP concepts from https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to

Then, you can do something like this from your statechart, assuming your `Bidder` agent type is embedded into `Main` in a population called `myBidders`:

```
double sumValue = sumWhere(main.myBidders, b->b.Budget, b->b.inState(assessBids));
```

The crucial thing is the first step, though ;)

Comment: Okay. It works. But how can I use that sumValue as a variable in my statechart? 

Like if the total value of that double sumValue exceeds 100 then it will go to stateB.

Comment: Happy to help. But on SOF, always open new issues for new questions, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow